# How to install Perl without sub-version number in path? (lib/perl5/5.X.Y -> lib/perl5/5.X)

Tags: perl

What is the easiest way to install Perl under `$prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X` instead of `$prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X.Y`? In current scheme all binaries linking against `libperl.dylib` stop working when I replace the old version of Perl with a new one (because a theoretically ABI-compatible library gets moved to a different location).

The `Configure` file contains

```
case "$installstyle" in
*lib/perl5*) set dflt privlib lib/$package/$version ;;
```

and `$version` is set to 5.X.Y, but I'm not sure how to safely fix that path without breaking anything.

Answer (score 1):

As mob has already suggested, don't try to change where perl is installing, instead just setup a symlink to point to the version that you want to use.

```
ln -s $prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X $prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X.Y
```

However, I believe you probably could use an introduction to [`perlbrew`](http://perlbrew.pl/).  perlbrew is a tool to manage multiple perl installations in your `$HOME` directory.  This would enable you to install a new version without risking your other development environments, and switch between versions of perl seamlessly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to "fix" the perl package(s) in a package manager. So "messing up" with `$HOME` is out of question. Multiple (sub)versions of perl are also out of question. The package manager already supports parallel installation of perl5.18, 5.16, 5.14, ... which is a pain already (for packages depending on perl). Supporting all sub-versions would be an exponential overkill. It's simply not an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
mv $prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X.Y $prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X
ln -s $prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X $prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X.Y
```

?

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. If I just move the folder after all the files have been installed, `libperl.dylib` will still think it's installed under `$prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X.Y` and any binary linking against it will keep looking under `$prefix/lib/perl5/perl5.X.Y` when I upgrade to 5.X.Z. I can use `install_name_tool` to fix this particular issue, but I suspect it's not the only one. I really want to fix this at configure time.